# HTML5 Audio Mixing

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I would like to make a web application where people can add recorded sounds and samples to a timeline.
I want it to output 1 soundfile (approximately 3min long) which will be send to the server.

Now I would like to do this with the HTML5 Audio API and found out that I could do this with the [AudioContext](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext) But Audiocontext is only supported in chrome.

Now I do dislike flash and I wanted to ask if there is any way to do this with HTML5 with decent browser support (so newest Chrome, IE and Firefox).

**Some thoughts:**
I could record audio using the HTML5 audio API and the user can add it to the timeline. When finished the client will upload all the audio files to the server including the location on the timetable. The server can combine the audio files to make it one file. Now this is an solution, but I would prefer to do this kind of work on the client side

Comment: Did you find a soultion already? If so could you share it? Thanks

Comment: No, not a solution which is working in all modern browsers. I think flash is (sadly) the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment in my opinion it is not possible (if it should be html5 and supported by IE and Firefox), see the List of Browser that Support the Audio API
**[Browsers with Audio API Support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio-api)**. But this Information could be outdated already.(these Browsers update so frequently)

You could wait, first serve only Chrome and hope the other Browser, catch up(IE might be a problem). Or you use Java (if you dont like flash). The other technologie out there is Silverlight, but it is "dead", so i wouldn't recommend it.

I hope my input helps a bit.